# Mathematical induction of this Code?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I don't really understand how I use proof by induction on this Code. 
I just wanna know how to prove the correctness of this code and algorithm.

Prove that we will never count items which already counted .

Algorithm for countCells(x,y)

> if the cell at(x,y) is outside
>
> the grid the result is 0;
>
> else if
>   the color of the cell at (x, y) is not the abnormal color     the result is 0;
>
> else
>   set the color of the cell at (x, y) to a temporary
>   color;    the result is 1 plus the number of cells in each piece of the
>   blob  that includes a nearest neighbor;

```
public int countCells(int x, int y)
{
    int result;

    if(x<0 || x>=N || y<0 || y>=N) // N is the maximum value of the matrix
        return 0;
    else if(!getColor(x,y).equals(ABNORMAL)) // 
        return 0;
    else
    {
        recolor(x, y, TEMPORARY);
        return 1 + countCells(x-1, y+1)  + countCells(x, y+1)
             + countCells(x+1, y+1)  + countCells(x-1, y)
             + countCells(x+1, y)  + countCells(x-1, y-1)
             + countCells(x, y-1)  + countCells(x+1, y-1)
    }
}
```

the following link show how this works

http://kin.naver.com/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=1&dirId=104&docId=186514818

Comment: *prove the correctness*? Can you specify what is the *correct* thing `countCells` should do?

Comment: Seems to me that this is sort of a floodfill algorithm, which counts the number of connected cells of abnormal color when starting at `(x, y)`. There's not much to prove, though.

Comment: You donot prove the correctness of code but of the algorithm as it based it. So does your algorithm count the total elements in the blob which contains a cell?

Comment: My computer science`s teacher said that i should prove this by induction. I have no idea how i prove. 

Yes. this algorithm just counts the total elements in the blob containing a cell.

Comment: Input : 2 dimensional matrix, x-coordinate, y-coordinate of any Point in the existing matrix.
output : the count of blob including pixel(x,y)

Comment: Did you ask your teacher to give you some hint about the problem or to help you with the proof you have to do ?

Comment: It might be "Prove that I cannot count Items that already counted."
thanks for asking, Gabriel L.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction

Prove for base case condition (n = 1)

Prove for all assumption step ( n = k )

Prove for inductive step + 1 (n = k + 1)

So call your function with a base for step 1, let k equal some other generic input, then do the input + 1.

Basically you want to test the edge cases of your functions to ensure that they work properly. Your teacher probably wants you to just write test conditions for the function above.

Comment: thanks. But i still dont understand how i get the proof by induction from this algorithm. I just posted how this algorithm works. Can you click the link that i wrote above?